# Square numbers and divisibility

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> If $kn+1$ and $(k+1)n+1$ are both perfect squares, then $2k+1$ divides n, where k and n are positive integers.

Case $k=1$:
Put $n+1=x^2$, $2n+1=y^2$. Quadratic residues can only be $0, 1 \mod 3$.
Hence
$n \equiv 1 \mod 3 \Rightarrow x^2 = n+1 \equiv 2 \mod 3$
$n \equiv 2 \mod 3 \Rightarrow y^2 = 2n+1 \equiv 5 \equiv 2 \mod 3$
Both of them are contradictions.

Case $k=2$:
Put $2n+1=x^2$, $3n+1=y^2$. Quadratic residues can only be $0, 1, 4 \mod 5$. Hence
$n \equiv 1 \mod 5 \Rightarrow x^2 = 2n+1 \equiv 3 \mod 5$
$n \equiv 2 \mod 5 \Rightarrow y^2 = 3n+1 \equiv 2 \mod 5$
$n \equiv 3 \mod 5 \Rightarrow x^2 = 2n+1 \equiv 2 \mod 5$
$n \equiv 4 \mod 5 \Rightarrow y^2 = 3n+1 \equiv 3 \mod 5$
All of them are contradictions.

Case $k=3$:
See [If 4n+1 and 3n+1 are both perfect sqares, then 56|n. How can I prove this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575733/if-4n1-and-3n1-are-both-perfect-sqares-then-56n-how-can-i-prove-this)

It might be possible to prove further individual cases for different k.
However I'm not sure if the statement is true for all positive k and if yes, how to prove it. 
Some observations:
If $kn+1 = x^2$ and $(k+1)n+1 = y^2$ we get
$y^2-x^2=n$
$y^2+x^2=(2k+1)n+2$
$(k+1)x^2-ky^2=1$
but I have no good idea how to proceed. Any hint/help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This answer explains how your question relates to the [Pell's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation) and points you to various online sources which can help you to solve your problem.

The equation you have, where I've switched the $x$ and $y$ around, of

$$(k+1)y^2 - kx^2 = 1 \implies kx^2 - (k+1)y^2 = -1 \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

is a form of a generalized Pell equation. There's an online [Solving a generalized Pell equation](http://www.numbertheory.org/php/pellab.html) page where it allows you to check the solubility of equations of the form

$$ax^2 - by^2 = \pm 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

where $1 \lt a \lt b$, $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $ab$ is not a perfect square. Your cases are satisfied with the right hand side of \eqref{eq1A} for $k \ge 2$ since $a = k$ and $b = k + 1$ satisfies $1 \lt k \lt k + 1$, $\gcd(k, k + 1) = 1$ and $k(k+1)$ not being a perfect square. To see the last point, note $k^2 \lt k(k+1) \lt (k+1)^2$.

The online solution calculator has a link to an explanation of how the algorithm works at [A Midpoint Criterion for the Diophantine Equation $ax^2 - by^2 = \pm 1$](http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/keith_midpoint.pdf). Also, it gives a link to a [GNU BC program source code](http://www.numbertheory.org/gnubc/pellab) implementation. Using this, if there are no solutions, then you're done for that $k$. Otherwise, you can check each solution to see if $\frac{x^2 - 1}{k + 1} = \frac{y^2 - 1}{k} = n$ where $n$ is an integer and, if so, then whether or not $2k + 1 \mid n$.

Alternatively, take the left hand side of \eqref{eq1A}, switch $x$ and $y$ around, and multiply both sides by $k + 1$, to get

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
(k+1)^2 x^2 - k(k+1)y^2 & = k + 1 \\
(x')^2 - Dy^2 & = N
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

where $x' = (k+1)x$. This is now in the more usual form of the generalized Pell equation. There's various sites with information about how to solve this, such as at [Solving the generalized Pell equation](https://thilinaatsympy.wordpress.com/2013/07/06/solving-the-generalized-pell-equation/), plus multiple posts on this site, e.g., at [Generalized Pell's equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2815199/generalized-pells-equation).

If you use this method, then if there are any solutions at all, for each one, first confirm $x = \frac{x'}{k+1}$ is an integer. If so, then do the other previous checks mentioned (but with $x$ and $y$ switched around) for a resulting integer $n$ and, if so, then that $2k + 1 \mid n$.

Comment: Right, this approach nicely explains how to transfer the problem into a Pell equation and how to solve it for each individual k.
That's for sure a big step forward. Unfortunately I think it does not provide a solution for all integer k.

Comment: @ThomasL I think you're right about not getting a solution for all $k$. I haven't determined the exact algebraic results but I'm fairly certain there will not be any easy way to determine, in general, which values of $k$ work & which don't. Nonetheless, you may wish to check on this yourself.

Comment: yes, I totally agree what you are saying. I have one more observation to add:  
$n=8(2k+1)$ is a solution in all cases:  
$$kn+1 = 8k(2k+1)+1 = 16k^2+8k+1 = (4k+1)^2$$  
$$(k+1)n+1 = 8(k+1)(2k+1)+1 = 8(2k^2+3k+1)+1 = 16k^2+24k+9 = (4k+3)^2$$